# PostgreSQL - pgAdmin 4 - COPY command not working with Schema

Tags: postgresql, copy

When trying to use the COPY command in pgAdmin 4 to copy a table from my database into a CSV file on disk

```
copy Administrative.REGIONS TO 'd:\temp\regions.csv' with csv header
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  schema "administrative" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.3 on a localhost (Win 10), and I have tried to use the same command on a public schema table and it worked fine. It didn't work on any table from any schema I tested apart from the public one.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance,
Ahmed

Comment: Have you tried the same from a different tool (`psql`, `DBeaver`, `Azure Data Studio`, etc) to see whether it's peculiar to pgAdmin4?

Comment: How do you know that the table exists?

Comment: Do the table and schema names contain upper case letters?

Comment: Thanks for answering; Bill, I didn't try any other tool, I will do that thanks. Mustaccio, I copy pasted the table names to ensure I didn't make a typo in the names thanks. Laurenz, I did copy paste the table names from the database to the Query window to ensure I captured the right table names, thanks.